# centos6.5's yum error : Input/output error

Tags: linux, yum, centos6.5

when i run yum command：

```
> yum
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/arraymodule.so: cannot read file data: Input/output error

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)]
```

Current version of Python is 2.6.6，not other。

system logs:

```
Oct 16 09:56:50 localhost kernel: mptbase: ioc0: LogInfo(0x31080000): Originator={PL}, Code={SATA NCQ Fail All Commands After Error}, SubCode(0x0000) cb_idx mptscsih_io_done
Oct 16 09:56:50 localhost kernel: LSI Debug log info 31080000 for channel 0 id 0
Oct 16 09:56:50 localhost kernel: mptbase: ioc0: LogInfo(0x31080000): Originator={PL}, Code={SATA NCQ Fail All Commands After Error}, SubCode(0x0000) cb_idx mptscsih_io_done
Oct 16 09:56:50 localhost kernel: LSI Debug log info 31080000 for channel 0 id 0
Oct 16 09:56:50 localhost kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Oct 16 09:56:50 localhost kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
Oct 16 09:56:50 localhost kernel: Info fld=0x4d59fc8
Oct 16 09:56:50 localhost kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sda]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Oct 16 09:56:50 localhost kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 04 d5 9f c8 00 00 08 00
Oct 16 09:56:50 localhost kernel: end_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 81108936
```

Who know how to fix? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Input/output error` indicates that you system cannot read the file. Your log indicates that the hard drive is failing. Reinstall yum through RPM if you must, but ultimately backup your critical data and salvage the storage array.

Comment: The hard disk has bad sectors ಥ_ಥ